# How to install developer add-ons for Gmail in G Suite accounts?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-workspace, gmail-addons

I am able to setup an Apps Scripts project to create a gmail add-on and can test it out using an @gmail.com account but the option to install developer add-ons does not show up in my G Suite account.

Alternatively, how do you deploy a gmail add-on to a private domain?  i tried following this https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide but it would not let me save the configuration if all I had selected was the 'Gmail add-on extension' checkbox.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Patrick, are you asking about a Google domain, as in a domain that uses G Suite, for business, education etc?

Comment: Correct, in this case for business

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain users are now able to publish a Gmail add-on private to their own domain. Furthermore, domain private add-ons do not require a Google review, you are free to build them and publish them at your leisure.

See the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/publish

Comment: I was able to confirm that it works.  Ruben's answer gets a consolation prize though as it was still helpful.  If I could upvote either of you I would :(

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the deployment of Gmail add-ons is restricted to selected developers.

Source: https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/gmail-add-ons-framework-now-available.html

> While you can't publish your add-on just yet, you can fill out this form to get notified when publishing is opened. We can’t wait to see what Gmail Add-ons you build!

Recently (January 2018) on the G Suite Update Alert blog it was announced new Gmail add-on features for G Suite accounts.

From https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/01/install-gmail-add-ons-for-your-domain.html

> In addition, we’re making it easier for developers to design Gmail
>   Add-ons specifically for their organizations. In the coming weeks,
>   developers in your domain will notice two changes:
>
> - They’ll be able to install Gmail Add-ons for their own G Suite accounts before they’re published, to aid in the development process.
>     Previously, this was limited to their personal Gmail accounts.
> - They’ll be able to publish Gmail Add-ons to users in their own G Suite domains. In addition, they'll be able to publish to the general
>     public, after requesting and receiving publication permission.
>
> Stay tuned to the G Suite Developers Blog to learn more about these
>   two developer capabilities and when they’ve launched.